# ¿Cómo funciona esto?

Tags: javascript, lista

Tengo curiosidad por entender como funciona esto, tengo mis dudas:

```
    function arrayToList(array) {
          let list = null;
          for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
          }
          return list;
```

¿Qué utilidad tiene esto?

```
        function listToArray(list) {
          let array = [];
          for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
            array.push(node.value);
          }
          return array;
        }
```

y este:

```
        function prepend(value, list) {
          return {value, rest: list};
        }
```

y este también:

```
        function nth(list, n) {
          if (!list) return undefined;
          else if (n == 0) return list.value;
          else return nth(list.rest, n - 1);
        }
```

Tengo una noción de lo que hace, pero estoy confundido.

Comment: Son muchas preguntas en una sola, minifica el problema

Comment: Hola Riven!, recién me doy cuenta de qué parecen múltiples problemas, pero en realidad es uno solo, todo ellos son parte de un ejercicio que traté de resolver.

Comment: Me refiero a que no todas hacen lo mismo, cada una tiene una logica diferente, funcionan de forma distinta

Comment: Voy a fragmentarlo.

Comment: Mejor ponle contexto. Qué esperas tú que haga o cuál es la salida esperada o algo que oriente la pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Dicha función, retorna un objecto con 2 propiedades, sus nombre son "value" y "rest"

"value" tendra el primer valor del argumento

"rest" es un objecto con las propiedades "value" y "rest, donde "value" es el siguiente valor del argumento y "rest" un objecto con las mismas propiedades descritas pero con el "rest" con los valores de la siguiente iteración.

```
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = { value: array[i], rest: list };
  }
  return list;
}

const output = arrayToList(test);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Output:

```
{
  "value": 1,
  "rest": {
    "value": 2,
    "rest": {
      "value": 3,
      "rest": {
        "value": 4,
        "rest": {
          "value": 5,
          "rest": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. la segunda devuelve un nuevo array con con los valores del argumento
3. Devuelve un objecto con las propiedades "value" y "rest", donde "value" es el primer argumento y "rest" es el segundo argumento

{ value: 'valor de prueba', rest: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

4. Es una función recursiva, la recursividad es una forma de resolver problemas de iteración, en resumen tu función se ejecutara a si misma hasta que se cumpla X condición, en este caso cuando list sea undefined o null o n sea igual a 0